# Ubuntu Wireless Adapter disconnected

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, wireless-access-point

I recently bought an Acer Travel Mate P446-M, installed with the wil6210 wireless adapter for 60 GHz communication. It was working perfectly with the Acer Docking station and the TP-Link AD7200 Talon router, both of which are equipped with 802.11ad.

However I then switched to Ubuntu and installed the wil6210 driver along with the firmware files, 'wil6210.brd' and 'wil6210.fw'. But I am now facing the issue that the Wilocity WiFi Network is always grayed out (showing a disconnected status) and I cannot connect to either my docking station or my router, although I can see their presence.

Any insights as to what I am missing here in order to connect my laptop to my Access points? I have also attached an image of what I mean by "Wilocity WiFi network is always grayed out".

Link for wireless diagnosis output.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25208663/

As you can see from the output above, the SSIDs "TP-LINK_8958_60G" and "AcerProDock_11ad_6015" are being detected by the laptop but the status of the "wlp2s0" device is shown to be disconnected. I hope this adds clarity to the question.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't see "Wilocity WiFi Network" in the image, nothing looks grayed out, also, you are connected to a wifi network.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have been more specific. The part of the options that is grayed out is

" Wi-Fi Network (Wilocity Wil6200 802.11ad Wireless Network Adapter)
   disconnected
   AcerProDock_11ad_6015 "

Yes I am connected to the 2.4/5Ghz WiFi spectrum, but am unable to get it to connect it to the 60 Ghz devices.

Comment: Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) for howto provide the needed info. Also, where did the driver and firmware came from?

Comment: I got the driver from a git repository available here:

http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kvalo/ath.git/

I used the firmware from a windows driver. Using this set up, I am able to see the 802.11ad APs in the environment, but am unable to associate with them since the Network option is always grayed out.

Comment: @mikewhatever : I have added the output from the wireless diagnosis procedure described in the post you referred me to earlier. I hope this adds clarity to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by disabling the encryption on the router. I am able to connect to the router now. It is fine for my purpose since I do not need encryption.